# Ir para a próxima instrução - C#

Tags: c#

Tenho um `if` e preciso que se caso seja `true` ele dê a mensagem abaixo e logo depois ele dá uma pausa no sistema ou continua em outra instrução. Deixei a palavra `BREAK` pra exemplificar onde preciso dessa codificação (mas o `BREAK` não funciona):

```
if (lanceSelecionado.ID_LANCE == null)
{
  await DisplayAlert("Comunicado", "Selecione um lance para exclusão!", "Ok");
  BREAK;
}
```

Comment: Se você der um `return;` ele sai da função, isso não resolve?

Comment: o `goto` não resolveria? https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto

Comment: goto não! Hahhaha

Comment: Caramba, o `return` fez exatamente o que eu esperava. @Roberto, se quiser colocar como resposta eu a defino como a melhor, acho justo.

Comment: Postei a resposta @DeividSouza, que bom que resolveu seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `return;` caso seja uma função de retorno `void`, por exemplo:

```
public void NomeDaFuncao()
{
    if (lanceSelecionado.ID_LANCE == null)
    {
      await DisplayAlert("Comunicado", "Selecione um lance para exclusão!", "Ok");
      return;
    }
}
```

Se for uma função com qualquer tipo de retorno é necessário fazer o `return` junto com um valor padrão, como por exemplo:

```
public int NomeDaFuncao()
{
    if (lanceSelecionado.ID_LANCE == null)
    {
      await DisplayAlert("Comunicado", "Selecione um lance para exclusão!", "Ok");
      return 0;
    }
}
```

O `return` tem como função retornar alguma coisa e parar de executar a função. Ele só executará mais alguma coisa se estiver dentro de um bloco `try finally`, nesses casos o que estiver dentro de `finally` será executado.

Answer (score -1):

Bom a sua pergunta está um pouco vaga. Caso queria que ele continue outra instrução é só chamar um método depois do DisplayAlert. Caso queria uma parada na aplicação poderá usar `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` ou `Console.ReadLine()` (a aplicação retornará depois de pressionar qualquer tecla). Bom tem N maneiras de implementar o que queres e se especificar melhor poderemos te ajudar da maneira mais adequada.